# Decoding VGA Signals on a microcontroller design concerns

Tags: microcontroller, analog, lcd, vga

I have a microblometer sensor that outputs a VGA signal with resolution 640 * 480 pixels. Lets say I want 30 FPS..
I would like to know what would be the easiest way to convert that video signal into digital to be processed on a uC then outputs the result after doing some operations into an LCD.

I know the design specs, I can provide an MCU with good memory > 1MBytes of RAM. I also don't want to work on FPGAs, it would be trivial to do.
[image]

Signal diagram:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, MCU is totally out of its depth here. You are solidly in flash ADC and FPGA territory.

Comment: @user_1818839 at these rates, flash ADCs are still probably not the architecture of choice, but I agree 100% with "needs an FPGA" and "can't be done with a MCU (alone)".

Comment: "What is the easiest way" questions are usually closed for being too broad. I happen to like them, but they don't really fit the Q&A format.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the picture after you acquire it?

Comment: @user253751 just display it

Comment: @MarcusMüller True, sometimes I forget how ADC tech has progressed over the years.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh display it on what? Sometimes it is useful to think about your whole system end-to-end, instead of focusing on only the component in the middle.

Comment: @user253751 on LCD TFT Screen

Comment: @AhmedSaleh what type of signal does the screen need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although VGA is really obsolete tech, there's still a lot of dedicated digitization ICs out there – especially because for two decades, TFT screens needed to support analog input. So, maybe go with that.

Alternatively, since your b**o**lometer doesn't give RGB, but only intensity values (i.e., not actually VGA at all, don't know why it's called VGA), it's likely you'd be happier with just a sufficeintly fast ADC being triggered on the PSYNC clock.

Technically, many ADCs can do that, being triggered by an external clock, but you'll have to make sure you consume the samples they generate at the same rate. That's really FPGA terrain you're entering there, not microcontroller stuff. Doesn't need to be a complex, expensive FPGA; realistically, at these low resolutions, all you need to have is maybe a few lines of buffer and a trigger on VSYNC to switch between these, as well as one on PSYNC delayed by the ADC's conversion latency.

For a back-of-envelope calculation: with a row being 640 px, and assuming you use a 10 bit ADC (which ADC you use will depend on your system's needs and noise – no need for quantisation noise much lower than system noise, you don't gain anything that way), that's 6400 bits per row.

You should buffer enough rows to allow the processor plenty of time to fetch the rows asynchronously, e.g. using QSPI, at rather loosely varying intervals.

Note, because I don't think you realize: for a 10 bit ADC giving you 640x480 px 30 times a second, you need to *sustain* nearly 100 Mb/s interface rate; it's not that clear that you'll find a MCU that will do that. "I can provide an MCU with > 1 MB of RAM" does not spark confidence that you realize this might be too much for most MCUs and might be deep into DSP territory, or only be done using things that usually fare as application processors. (1 MB barely covers one third of a frame, so it seems you've not even done a back-of-envelope calculation!) Most probably, whatever you need to do to convert your data to something that can be displayed will also be done on the FPGA, or on a smartphone or laptop-class CPU.

> I also don't want to work on FPGAs, it would be trivial to do.

It's an FPGA's job; do it on an FPGA. Congratulations that you think working with an FPGA is trivial! I would not think so, but I only worked with large FPGAs for a couple of months.

A microcontroller is not well-suited for this timing-centric, low-complexity, hight-throughput kind of work. You still will use a microcontroller to read the rows from the FPGA's buffer and compute what you display on the LCD.

(Alternatively: you could try to do the sampling in the MCU itself, but MCU ADC's are probably not what you want, noise-wise, if you're processing something coming from a bolometer, plus, you'd have a hard time finding a MCU with an internal, externally trigerrable ca 10 MS/s ADC, or able to trigger something at 20 MS/s as necessary if you do not sync. So, no, there's really no way to do this without some external logic controlling the ADC, far as I can tell.)

Comment: Many microcontrollers have realtime subsystems that can easily push lots of data around, and do simple things on said data - like timing. The hard part for an MCU is typically the data processing. Then there's a question what's an MCU: is the chip on a RPi 4 an MCU? Because it sure could do that, if any MCU could without using a math-heavy FPGA.

Comment: Many thanks, can you elaborate why there are two analog output pins in that sensor ?

Comment: plus 1, is it possible to elaborate more how would I use the VSync, HSYNC signals ?

Comment: Hm, that would probably be a separate question here, not something someone could answer in the comments. However, I explained that in rough strokes in the answer myself: obviously, you'll need to use PSYNC to trigger the conversion of a single pixel, you'd use HSYNC to advance one row buffer, and VSYNC to denote the beginning of a frame. The rest depends on your signal processing architecture. Since we have no idea what you plan to do with the raw data to convert it to an image (that's super vague! You'll need to range-adjust, color-map, scale, shift…), we can't advise.

Comment: Yes I just need to output it to an LCD that's all... So I would use two external interrupts signals for a complete of a frame and beginning of frame, read pixels using those triggers right ?

Comment: "that's all": as said, that's a very underdefined statement. Again, don't ask new questions in the comments.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a digital and an analog signal?  Each analog output, depending on how it's created, can represent many different values.  When you want to represent that analog value in a digital form, you need to decide how many of those many possible analog values you want to represent.  This is determined by the number of bits used.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do it on an MCU, then the only one I know of that would be capable of doing it all on one chip - video sampling, processing, and analog output as VGA or digital as HDMI - then it'd be [Parallax Propeller 2](https://www.parallax.com/propeller-2/).

Whether it could do processing is of course dependent on what sort of processing you need. But if your flow is essentially get a frame, find a feature, annotate frame, send to display - then if the feature finding can fit into the memory and CPU time available, it'll work OK.

The chip has 64 pins, each of which can be an 8-bit A/D sampling at a couple MS/s, or a 16-bit D/A, and groups of 8 can be HDMI outputs, etc. The heavy stuff is done in software, but it's a pretty fast chip: 8 cores @ 300 MHz each.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that MCU, thanks for recommendation. is it possible to elaborate more how would I use the VSync, HSYNC signals ? and why there are two analog output pin signals ?